# mysqld out of memory with plenty (?) of memory

Tags: mysql, out-of-memory

I have a busy server running Percona 5.6.34-79.1-1.xenial on Ubuntu 16.04. It works great, however, every few weeks, mysqld is shot by out-of-memory killer and I'm not able to find out why.

```
root@master02:~# grep Out /var/log/syslog
Apr  6 13:37:03 master02 kernel: [17420955.874564] Out of memory: Kill process 36138 (mysqld) score 659 or sacrifice child
```

So it was killed at 13:37:03.

However, just 2 seconds before, it was using around 110 GB RAM (the system has ~160 GB RAM), with some 55 GB free:

```
root@master02:~# cat /root/logs/free/free-2017-04-06-13\:36\:01.log
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      165050752   109560372      593508      189240    54896872    54434632
Swap:             0           0           0

root@master02:~# cat /root/logs/free/free-2017-04-06-13\:37\:01.log
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      165050752   109582416      602704      189624    54865632    54412072
Swap:             0           0           0

root@master02:~# cat /root/logs/free/free-2017-04-06-13\:38\:01.log
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      165050752    17982728    92226488      189200    54841536   146007904
Swap:             0           0           0
```

my.cnf has "innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 130G" set. I don't find it very likely that mysqld allocated some extra 50 GB in 2 secs and was killed (though I may be wrong of course).

Here is a dmesg showing full OOM - is it some memory allocation issue which is tunable? I'd appreciate any hints here.

```
[17420955.874279] mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x26000c0, order=2, oom_score_adj=0
[17420955.874282] mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0-1
[17420955.874287] CPU: 4 PID: 36138 Comm: mysqld Not tainted 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu
[17420955.874288] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 11/11/2016
[17420955.874290]  0000000000000286 00000000dba8c85b ffff88142f4bbaf0 ffffffff813f7583
[17420955.874292]  ffff88142f4bbcc8 ffff8827ac8db800 ffff88142f4bbb60 ffffffff8120ad5e
[17420955.874295]  ffffffff81cd2dc7 0000000000000000 ffffffff81e67760 0000000000000206
[17420955.874297] Call Trace:
[17420955.874304]  [<ffffffff813f7583>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[17420955.874307]  [<ffffffff8120ad5e>] dump_header+0x5a/0x1c5
[17420955.874311]  [<ffffffff81192722>] oom_kill_process+0x202/0x3c0
[17420955.874312]  [<ffffffff81192b49>] out_of_memory+0x219/0x460
[17420955.874315]  [<ffffffff81198abd>] __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.88+0x8fd/0xa70
[17420955.874317]  [<ffffffff81198eb6>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x286/0x2a0
[17420955.874319]  [<ffffffff81198f6b>] alloc_kmem_pages_node+0x4b/0xc0
[17420955.874323]  [<ffffffff8107ea5e>] copy_process+0x1be/0x1b70
[17420955.874326]  [<ffffffff811c164d>] ? handle_mm_fault+0xcbd/0x1820
[17420955.874328]  [<ffffffff810805a0>] _do_fork+0x80/0x360
[17420955.874329]  [<ffffffff81080929>] SyS_clone+0x19/0x20
[17420955.874333]  [<ffffffff818384f2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[17420955.874343] Mem-Info:
[17420955.874354] active_anon:27160197 inactive_anon:28926 isolated_anon:0
                   active_file:5497699 inactive_file:7563747 isolated_file:0
                   unevictable:914 dirty:2486 writeback:0 unstable:0
                   slab_reclaimable:556865 slab_unreclaimable:45056
                   mapped:20876 shmem:47414 pagetables:71927 bounce:0
                   free:154548 free_pcp:64 free_cma:0
[17420955.874357] Node 0 DMA free:15904kB min:8kB low:8kB high:12kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15988kB managed:15904kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[17420955.874361] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3706 80497 80497 80497
[17420955.874370] Node 0 DMA32 free:311248kB min:2072kB low:2588kB high:3108kB active_anon:3411180kB inactive_anon:1348kB active_file:4kB inactive_file:8kB unevictable:280kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3915776kB managed:3835152kB mlocked:280kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:524kB shmem:2308kB slab_reclaimable:65844kB slab_unreclaimable:14292kB kernel_stack:1760kB pagetables:13784kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
[17420955.874373] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 76791 76791 76791
[17420955.874376] Node 0 Normal free:143060kB min:42940kB low:53672kB high:64408kB active_anon:62267420kB inactive_anon:31360kB active_file:7207656kB inactive_file:7550284kB unevictable:3296kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:79953920kB managed:78634400kB mlocked:3296kB dirty:3116kB writeback:0kB mapped:18940kB shmem:49312kB slab_reclaimable:838024kB slab_unreclaimable:78600kB kernel_stack:51840kB pagetables:159192kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:136kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:76 all_unreclaimable? no
[17420955.874380] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[17420955.874383] Node 1 Normal free:147980kB min:45088kB low:56360kB high:67632kB active_anon:42962188kB inactive_anon:82996kB active_file:14783136kB inactive_file:22704696kB unevictable:80kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:83886080kB managed:82565296kB mlocked:80kB dirty:6828kB writeback:0kB mapped:64040kB shmem:138036kB slab_reclaimable:1323592kB slab_unreclaimable:87332kB kernel_stack:48624kB pagetables:114732kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:120kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
[17420955.874387] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[17420955.874390] Node 0 DMA: 0*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB (U) 2*64kB (U) 1*128kB (U) 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB (M) = 15904kB
[17420955.874398] Node 0 DMA32: 13480*4kB (UME) 6994*8kB (UME) 2710*16kB (UME) 714*32kB (UMEH) 354*64kB (UMEH) 225*128kB (UMEH) 107*256kB (UMEH) 52*512kB (UME) 29*1024kB (UMEH) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 311248kB
[17420955.874408] Node 0 Normal: 29953*4kB (UMEH) 2985*8kB (UMEH) 1*16kB (H) 0*32kB 2*64kB (H) 2*128kB (H) 2*256kB (H) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (H) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 145628kB
[17420955.874416] Node 1 Normal: 36438*4kB (UME) 412*8kB (UMEH) 2*16kB (H) 2*32kB (H) 0*64kB 1*128kB (H) 1*256kB (H) 2*512kB (H) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 150552kB
[17420955.874425] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[17420955.874427] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[17420955.874428] Node 1 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[17420955.874429] Node 1 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[17420955.874430] 13109543 total pagecache pages
[17420955.874431] 0 pages in swap cache
[17420955.874440] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[17420955.874441] Free swap  = 0kB
[17420955.874442] Total swap = 0kB
[17420955.874443] 41942941 pages RAM
[17420955.874444] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[17420955.874444] 680253 pages reserved
[17420955.874445] 0 pages cma reserved
[17420955.874446] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[17420955.874447] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[17420955.874457] [  677]     0   677    38915    23334      80       3        0             0 systemd-journal
[17420955.874461] [  698]     0   698    25742       47      17       3        0             0 lvmetad
[17420955.874469] [  729]     0   729    11545     1219      23       3        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
[17420955.874472] [ 1112]   109  1112    25081      492      19       3        0             0 systemd-timesyn
[17420955.874474] [ 1333]     0  1333     4030      637      12       3        0             0 dhclient
[17420955.874475] [ 1541]     0  1541     6932      547      19       3        0             0 cron
[17420955.874477] [ 1552]     0  1552   365572     5403      79       7        0             0 snapd
[17420955.874479] [ 1559]   102  1559    10725      667      26       3        0          -900 dbus-daemon
[17420955.874480] [ 1570]     0  1570    77473      728      21       3        0             0 lxcfs
[17420955.874482] [ 1576]   101  1576    64099     1008      27       3        0             0 rsyslogd
[17420955.874484] [ 1578]   106  1578     1884      403       9       3        0             0 vnstatd
[17420955.874486] [ 1580]     0  1580     1100      322       8       3        0             0 acpid
[17420955.874488] [ 1582]     0  1582    68674     1100      37       3        0             0 accounts-daemon
[17420955.874489] [ 1584]     0  1584     6511      378      18       3        0             0 atd
[17420955.874491] [ 1593]     0  1593    16380      700      36       3        0         -1000 sshd
[17420955.874493] [ 1595]     0  1595     7157      635      18       3        0             0 systemd-logind
[17420955.874495] [ 1599]     0  1599     7470      139      19       3        0             0 cgmanager
[17420955.874497] [ 1618]     0  1618     3344      116      11       3        0             0 mdadm
[17420955.874498] [ 1622]     0  1622     1306      441       8       3        0             0 iscsid
[17420955.874500] [ 1623]     0  1623     1431      916       8       3        0           -17 iscsid
[17420955.874511] [ 1717]     0  1717     3619      388      12       3        0             0 agetty
[17420955.874513] [ 1718]     0  1718     3665      343      12       3        0             0 agetty
[17420955.874515] [ 1731]     0  1731     5025      653      15       3        0             0 irqbalance
[17420955.874517] [ 1744]     0  1744    69272      719      39       3        0             0 polkitd
[17420955.874519] [ 2484]  1001  2484    11312      218      27       3        0             0 systemd
[17420955.874520] [ 2488]  1001  2488    15805      475      34       3        0             0 (sd-pam)
[17420955.874523] [ 6289]     0  6289     7718     1364      19       3        0             0 tmux
[17420955.874531] [ 6290]     0  6290     5381      924      15       3        0             0 bash
[17420955.874533] [ 6306]     0  6306     2158      395      10       3        0             0 mysqld_safe
[17420955.874537] [36138]   107 36138 43942177 27121187   70971     157        0             0 mysqld
[17420955.874539] [78610]   108 78610     5992      577      16       3        0             0 nrpe
[17420955.874542] [19441]     0 19441    24876     1740      54       3        0             0 sshd
[17420955.874543] [19447]  1008 19447    11312     1147      27       3        0             0 systemd
[17420955.874555] [19449]  1008 19449    15817      487      34       3        0             0 (sd-pam)
[17420955.874557] [19575]  1008 19575    24876      834      51       3        0             0 sshd
[17420955.874558] [19576]     0 19576    14970      933      34       3        0             0 sudo
[17420955.874560] [19577]     0 19577     5388     1343      16       3        0             0 bash
[17420955.874561] [26883]     0 26883     8430     5113      22       5        0             0 mysqld_exporter
[17420955.874564] Out of memory: Kill process 36138 (mysqld) score 659 or sacrifice child
[17420955.890336] Killed process 36138 (mysqld) total-vm:175768708kB, anon-rss:108470860kB, file-rss:13888kB
```

Here is my.cnf file:

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /var/lib/mysql-binlogs/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 7
sync-binlog                    = 1

binlog-format                  = MIXED

# REPLICATION #
server-id                      = 1
auto_increment_offset          = 1

# total number of master servers
auto_increment_increment       = 2

log-slave-updates              = 1
relay-log                      = /var/lib/mysql-binlogs/relay-bin
slave-net-timeout              = 60

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 4096

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 125G
innodb_large_prefix            = 1
innodb_file_format             = Barracuda

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 0
slow-query-log                 = 0
slow-query-log-file            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

# OTHER SETUP #
character_set_server           = utf8mb4
collation-server               = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect                   = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'

skip-name-resolve              = 1

max_connections                = 12288
wait_timeout                   = 120
connect_timeout                = 30
interactive_timeout            = 120
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you are using this along with PHP and Apache. It is most likely that you will find what is causing this issue in one of those application's log files.

Note the time of failure in the MySQL log and then look in the other log files during that time period and you should find the clues that will ultimately lead you to an answer.

I should also note that OOM chooses what service to shut down when the system runs out of memory and even though shut down it may not have been the service that created the issue.

Comment: mysqld is the only big user on this server ("second biggest" is probably sshd or rsyslogd). There is no webserver, PHP and similar there (they run on different machines).

Comment: OK then, you might want to post your MySQL config. There may be something in it that needs to be changed.

Comment: Added my.cnf below the original question.

Comment: I would agree with @Bill-Karwin's answer and it made me think that you should use ps -aux to take a look at what is running on your server. That might also give you a clue. It could be that sessions aren't being closed.

Comment: We also dump "ps auxf" and "top -b -c -n 1" every minute on that server. There just isn't anything big on this server, except mysqld. Also, OOM shows the processes, their RAM usage and their OOM score. You can see there isn't anything close to mysqld in terms of memory usage. And that mysqld was using around 100 GB RAM at the time it was killed (if I'm reading it correctly).

Comment: Yes, exactly, you describe the same situation i've on my server, where there's just mysql running and nothing more.
i don't know what's going on, i've no clue on logs, also i see that RAM is stucked to 90% of usage, my buffer pool is 50 GB on a machine with 70 GB of RAM, and the occupied RAM never decrease...how is possibile that never decrease?

Answer (score 1):

```
max_connections                = 12288
```

This is an eyebrow-raising number. Why so high? Do you use that many connections? You can monitor `show global status like 'max_used_connections'` to find out. Unfortunately this number is reset when mysqld restarts, so you'll have to monitor it externally.

There are some buffers that are allocated per connection. So if you ever do get a spike in the number of connections, it could consume a lot of memory suddenly. This is uncommon, but possible.

I suspect that @Vilmos is right, that you have some other process on the server that suddenly consumed the remaining memory, and then the OOM killer decided that innocent little mysqld was the process to kill, even though the memory exhaustion wasn't its fault.

There's a lesson about life in there. :-)

You might want to enable a swap partition, and then set up alerting if the swap is used too heavily. Then at least mysqld won't be killed, but it may slow down a lot. And you may be able to find out which process is running that has consumed too much memory.

Comment: Answer, part 1: "max_connections = 12288" is expected.

This is a busy server, and the usual number of connections is around 6000, typical network traffic - 20-30 MBytes/s sending, 10-20 MBytes/s receiving, coming from MySQL queries. However, when we update the application servers and they are restarted, the number of connections jump to around 10000-11000 (old connections, in Sleep state, are still opened for 120 secs, new ones are being added).

At the time the OOM happened, there were around 6000 connections to MySQL, business like usual.

Comment: Answer, part 2: 
This is a dedicated MySQL server. As I've mentioned before - there isn't anything big running there besides mysqld. The suggestion that some random process like sshd or rsyslogd suddenly used 50 GB in 2 seconds, caused the kernel to kill mysqld, and is not even shown in the OOM dmesg, is even less likely.

Comment: Hi @Tomasz, did you find what was the reasons of this problem?
I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @Jung no, I did not find the cause. Eventually, I've given up debugging this and added more RAM to the server. Also, we use Percona 5.7 now.

Comment: @Tomasz thanks for the feedback. I've also added 10 GB of RAM one month ago, when the problem occurred for the first time, but it happened again 2 days ago, MySQL 5.6 here.
What a strange behaviour, the RAM was literally eated in 1 minute and the server crashed.

Comment: @Jung You might like to look at this bug, it has pretty detailed information. It might or might not apply to your case. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97935

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the link, i read it but it seems they haven't found a solution, right?
I'm using 5.6 version and  i see the same behaviour of the bug reported... i've a master with 2 slaves, all 3 with 70 GB of RAM and 50 GB of innodb buffer pool, 3 servers with just mysql running, no others processes.

The master crashed 2 times in one months, killed on Linux host cause OOM, also i see the slaves stucked with 92% of RAM occupied,   i've just checked the first slave right now, no queries running, it's doing nothing at all but the RAM usage is  92%, seems the RAM is never freed.

Comment: Right, the bug is unresolved. MySQL hasn't even agreed that it's a bug (the status is "Open" but we hope they will acknowledge it and change that to "Verified"). If you believe you are affected by this bug, you can log into bugs.mysql.com and click the "Affects Me" button for this bug.